# I need to add image elements to the DOM for each image in the array using fetch

Tags: javascript, image, fetch-api

```
function ceo() {
    const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4" 
    fetch(imgUrl)
    .then(resp => resp.json)
    .then(json => renderImg(json))

}
// needed help with concepts 
function renderImg(images) {
    const loc = document.querySelector('div')
    images.(Image => {
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.innerHTML = Image.message;
       loc.appendChild(img)
    });
}



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ceo()
})
```

Add JavaScript that:

on page load, fetches the images using the url above:

- parses the response as JSON
- adds image elements to the DOM for each image in the array

Comment: But what's the question? Also `resp => resp.json()`

Answer (score 1):

There are few errors in your code.

1. It should be `resp.json()` not `resp.json`.
2. Then you need to loop over the `message` property in the incoming data `images.message.forEach()`.
3. Set `img.src`, not `img.innerHTML`.

```js
function ceo() {
  const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4"
  fetch(imgUrl)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => renderImg(json))
}

// needed help with concepts 
function renderImg(images) {
  const loc = document.querySelector('div')
  images.message.forEach(Image => {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = Image;
    loc.appendChild(img)
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ceo()
})
```

```html
<div></div>
```